# How to cycle through the files in a corpus: Python

Tags: python, nltk, corpus

I have other methods that need to work with each individual txt file within my corpus. How can I cycle through them?

```
import nltk
from nltk.corpus import PlaintextCorpusReader as pcr

def main():
    cor = corpus()
    # for every text file in the corpus:
        #Do this method

def corpus():
    corpus_root='corpus/'
    corp = pcr(corpus_root,'.*\.txt')
    corp = corp.raw()
    return corp

main()
```

Comment: Could you post the file structure in `corpus`? Also, what are you looking to do with the files?

Comment: This is an nltk question; the structure is clear from the argument to `pcr`.

Answer (score 2):

The nltk corpus readers have a method `fileids()` that you should use:

```
mycorpus = pcr(corpus_root, r'.*\.txt')

for fname in mycorpus.fileids():
    text = mycorpus.raw(fname)
    sents = mycorpus.sents(fname)
    # or whatever
```

When you call `raw()`, `sents()` `words()`, `tagged_words()`, etc. with a filename, you get the contents of just the file you specify. You can also pass a list of filenames, if you ever want a multi-file subset of your corpus.

PS. It doesn't make a difference here, but you should use raw strings for regexps (see above)

Answer (score 0):

you can use glob

```
import glob
glob.glob("corpus/*")
```

Answer (score 0):

Unless I'm mistaken, I think this has a pretty simple answer:

```
# for every text file in the corpus
for text_file in cor:
    # Do this method
    my_method(text_file)
```